# d3v4 - transform translate with dynamic value

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am trying to draw a diamond shape in `svg`. The idea is drawing a `rect` in square then rotate 45 degree then translate it to specific position:

```
d3.select(this.$el).select('svg').selectAll('g')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('transform', 
      function(d,i) {
      return d3.svg.transform()
          .translate(d.pricetargetpos - 5, (i+1) *itemh - itemh/2 -5)
          .rotate(-45);
      })
    .attr('width','10')
    .attr('height','10')
    .attr('fill', '#000000')
```

But it give me error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: i don't think there is anything like `d3.svg.transform()` which d3 version are you using.

Comment: There is a plugin [d3-transform](https://github.com/trinary/d3-transform) that works like this. Do you have it installed? Be sure to use the latest commit. In v4 you instantiate the serializer with `d3.transform()`, while in v3 it said `d3.svg.transform()` (See [this](https://github.com/trinary/d3-transform/commit/b8403370829e7a26b0b333f22dec9bea1c73a65a) commit)